# How to get week over week counts of cohorts in sql?

Tags: sql, postgresql, aggregate-functions

I need to give each user a type of either ‘A’, ‘B’, ‘C’  based on how often they visited a certain page during a 4 month time range, and then count the number of users per user_type per week.

In the query each week is its own 8 week cohort, meaning, if we start on the week of 11/27/22 then we go back another 7 weeks to the week of 10/9/22. For the cohort we determine a user’s preliminary user type by the following:

A users → Appears at least 4 consecutive weeks,
B users → appears at least 3 weeks, can be nonconsecutive
C users → appears less than 3 times

Then a scoring system is calculated based on the preliminary user_type for each of the cohorts.
For each cohort a user appeared as an “A” they received 3 points, 1 point for a “B”, and -1 points for a “C”. The user will also be given an additional .5 points if they were either an A or a B and appeared within the past 4 weeks.

We sum the scores for the past 8 week cohorts and If the user has a total score of at least 12, then their overall user_type is an A for the cohort. A minimum total score of 4 makes them a B for the cohort and anything less is a C.

The data below is an example of a user being a B user for the cohort of 11/20 - 8/7/22 and then the next week the user being a C user for the cohort of 11/27/22 - 8/14/22. I am only trying to show the overall user_type for the past two weeks so data points for the 8 week cohort user type and 8 week cohort user type point value are left null if they are not relevant for the past two weeks.

---

**For example,**

| Week | Visited Page | User Type | User Type Value |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 8/7/22 | Yes | - | - |
| 8/14/22 | No | - | - |
| 8/21/22 | No | - | - |
| 9/4/22 | No | - | - |
| 9/11/22 | Yes | - | - |
| 9/18/22 | No | - | - |
| 9/25/22 | No | - | - |
| 10/2/22 | Yes | B | 1 |
| 10/9/22 | Yes | B | 1 |
| 10/16/22 | No | B | 1 |
| 10/23/22 | No | B | 1 |
| 10/30/22 | No | B | 1 |
| 11/6/22 | No | C | -1 |
| 11/13/22 | No | C | -1 |
| 11/20/22 | Yes | B | 1.5 |
| 11/27/22 | No | C | -1 |

*For the week of 11/20/22 the user is a 'B' user type with a final score of 4.5

*For the week of 11/27/22 the user is a 'C' user type witha final score of 2.5

---

The Query below can find the cohort’s user_type for the current week, but I am unsure how to add on to this query so that I can determine the cohort’s user_type from week to week.
Any help is appreciated.

```
select 
user_type,
type_count
from (
select distinct
user_type,
count(user_type) over (partition by user_type) type_count,

case when user_type = 'A' then 1
    when user_type = 'B' then 2 
    else 3 end r2

from (
select distinct
user_id,
total_score,
case when total_score >= 12 then 'A'
     when total_score >= 4 then 'B' 
     else 'C'
     end user_type

from (
select 
user_id,
user_type,
case when user_type = 'A' and wk0 >= (date_trunc('week', (date_add('week',-4,getdate())))) then 3.5
     when user_type = 'A' then 3
     when user_type = 'B' and wk0 >= (date_trunc('week', (date_add('week',-4,getdate())))) then 1.5
     when user_type = 'B' then 1
     when user_type = 'C' then -1
end user_score,
sum(user_score) over (partition by user_id) total_score,
wk0,
r
from (

select
user_id,
case when wk7_range <= 49 and wk5_diff = 7 and wk6_diff = 7 and wk7_diff = 7 then 'A'
when wk6_range <= 49 and wk4_diff = 7 and wk5_diff = 7 and wk6_diff = 7 then 'A'
when wk5_range <= 49 and wk3_diff = 7 and wk4_diff = 7 and wk5_diff = 7 then 'A'
when wk4_range <= 49 and wk2_diff = 7 and wk3_diff = 7 and wk4_diff = 7 then 'A'
when wk3_range <= 49 and wk1_diff = 7 and wk2_diff = 7 and wk3_diff = 7 then 'A'
when wk7_range <= 49 then 'B'
when wk6_range <= 49 then 'B'
when wk5_range <= 49 then 'B'
when wk4_range <= 49 then 'B'
when wk3_range <= 49 then 'B'
when wk2_range <= 49 then 'B'
when wk1_diff > 49 then 'C'
when wk2_range > 49 then 'C'
when wk1 is null then 'C'
when wk2 is null then 'C'
else 'NA'
end user_type,
wk0,
dense_rank() over (order by wk0 desc) r
from (

SELECT
user_id,
wk0,
wk1,
extract(DAY from (wk0 - wk1)) wk1_diff,
wk2,
extract(DAY from (wk0 - wk2)) wk2_range,
extract(DAY from (wk1 - wk2)) wk2_diff,
wk3,
extract(DAY from (wk0 - wk3)) wk3_range,
extract(DAY from (wk2 - wk3)) wk3_diff,
wk4,
extract(DAY from (wk0 - wk4)) wk4_range,
extract(DAY from (wk3 - wk4)) wk4_diff,
wk5,
extract(DAY from (wk0 - wk5)) wk5_range,
extract(DAY from (wk4 - wk5)) wk5_diff,
wk6,
extract(DAY from (wk0 - wk6)) wk6_range,
extract(DAY from (wk5 - wk6)) wk6_diff,
wk7,
extract(DAY from (wk0 - wk7)) wk7_range,
extract(DAY from (wk6 - wk7)) wk7_diff
from (

SELECT
user_id,
wk0,
lag(wk0,1) over (partition by user_id order by wk0) wk1,
lag(wk0,2) over (partition by user_id order by wk0) wk2,
lag(wk0,3) over (partition by user_id order by wk0) wk3,
lag(wk0,4) over (partition by user_id order by wk0) wk4,
lag(wk0,5) over (partition by user_id order by wk0) wk5,
lag(wk0,6) over (partition by user_id order by wk0) wk6,
lag(wk0,7) over (partition by user_id order by wk0) wk7

from (

SELECT distinct
user_id,

(date_trunc('week', CAST((CAST(visits."timestamp" AS timestamp) + INTERVAL '1 day') AS timestamp)) - INTERVAL '1 day') AS wk0
FROM Visits

WHERE "visits"."timestamp" >= (date_trunc('week', (date_add('week',18,getdate()))))


order by user_id, "timestamp" desc
)
)
)
)
where user_type <> 'NA'
and r <=9
and r > 1
order by user_id, user_type, wk0 desc
)
)
)
order by r2
```

Comment: Can you replace the user type example as a picture by plain text ? Then `getdate()` is not a standard function in postgres, what is its definition ?

Comment: you can see the example as a table instead of an image.
For the getdate() function, I use it to return current date

Comment: in your example, the `User Type` column corresponds to the intermediate calculation "A users → Appears at least 4 consecutive weeks, B users → appears at least 3 weeks, can be nonconsecutive C users → appears less than 3 times" **but not to the final calculation** : "We sum the scores for the past 8 week cohorts and If the user has a total score of at least 12, then their overall user_type is an A for the cohort. A minimum total score of 4 makes them a B for the cohort and anything less is a C". See my [adapted proposal](https://dbfiddle.uk/_G8vc2kP)

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that `"visits"."timestamp"` is of type timestamp, I would suggest :

To create a view where you track which user_id is active on which week :

```
CREATE OR REPLACE VIEW active_user (user_id, week) AS
SELECT DISTINCT
       user_id
     , date_trunc('week', timestamp)
  FROM visit ;
```

Then create a function to check 4 consecutive weeks within an array of weeks :

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION check_4_consecutive_weeks (week_array timestamp[]) RETURNS boolean LANGUAGE sql IMMUTABLE AS $$
SELECT max (c.count) = 4
FROM ( SELECT count(*) OVER (ORDER BY week RANGE BETWEEN CURRENT ROW AND interval '4 weeks' FOLLOWING) AS count
         FROM unnest(week_array) AS week
) AS c ; $$ ;
```

Then the query is :

```
SELECT f.week
     , count(*) FILTER (WHERE f.total_score >= 12) AS count_A
     , count(*) FILTER (WHERE f.total_score >= 4 AND total_score < 12) AS count_B
     , count(*) FILTER (WHERE f.total_score < 4) AS count_C
  FROM (
SELECT s.user_id
     , s.week
     , sum(s.week_score) OVER (PARTITION BY s.user_id ORDER BY week RANGE BETWEEN interval '8 weeks' PRECEDING AND CURRENT ROW) AS total_score
  FROM (
SELECT user_id
     , week
     , CASE
         WHEN check_4_consecutive_weeks(array_agg(week) OVER w) THEN 3
         WHEN count(*) OVER w >= 3 THEN 1
         ELSE -1
       END
     + CASE
         WHEN count(*) OVER w >= 3 AND count(*) OVER (PARTITION BY user_id ORDER BY week RANGE BETWEEN CURRENT ROW AND interval '4 weeks' FOLLOWING) >= 1 THEN 0.5
         ELSE 0
       END AS week_score
  FROM active_user
 WINDOW w AS (PARTITION BY user_id ORDER BY week RANGE BETWEEN interval '8 weeks' PRECEDING AND CURRENT ROW)
) AS s
) AS f
GROUP BY f.week
```

see [window function call](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-expressions.html#SYNTAX-WINDOW-FUNCTIONS) in the manual

see the test result in [dbfiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/mOUfLg0v)

Comment: Thank you, this is helpful! unfortunately, I don't have permission to create a view in database. I'd appreciate if you have a different solution.

Comment: in the query you can replace `FROM active_user` by `FROM (SELECT DISTINCT user_id, date_trunc('week', timestamp) AS week FROM visit) AS v`